# Flip upside down vertex shader (GLES)

Tags: glsl, shader, flip, vertex

Given the next vertex shader, what is the simplest, most efficient and fastest way to flip the coordinates upside down, so the fragment shader will produce and upside down image?

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;                                                  
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    v_texcoord = a_texcoord.st;
    gl_Position = a_position;
}
```

Comment: The vertex position coordinates or the texture coordinates? Also, wouldn't it make more sense to put this into the transform you use for those positions (assuming that you intend to do some transformation).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just flip `v_texcoord`. So e.g.

```
v_texcoord = a_texcoord.st * vec2(1.0, -1.0);
```

Or, I guess:

```
v_texcoord = vec2(a_texcoord.s, 1.0 - a_texcoord.t);
```

Depending on what exactly you want to happen to the range of `.t`.

Comment: Excellent! Uses "vec2(a_texcoord.s, 1.0 - a_texcoord.t)" and works perfect.

Comment: v_texcoord = vec2(a_texcoord.s, 1.0 - a_texcoord.t); - easy and beauty solution, thanks

Comment: v_texcoord = vec2(a_texcoord.s, 1.0 - a_texcoord.t); works fine